# Setting up thin webserver for production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thin

I am trying to setup at Thin webser production mode on a ubuntu 12.04 server.

I followed this guide http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/ubuntu-thin-web-server-for-ruby

But when I go to

www.mydomain,com:3000 I just a timeout.

I tried

```
curl http://localhost:3000
```

from the server itself which gives

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host


cat /etc/thin1.9.1/test_blueprinter.yml 
--- 
timeout: 30
daemonize: true
port: 3000
max_conns: 1024
log: log/thin.log
wait: 30
require: []

address: 0.0.0.0
chdir: /home/lab/rails_apps/blueprinter
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
environment: production
max_persistent_conns: 512
servers: 1
```

How can I see my server is running and if so why cant I access it?

**UPDATE**

So i can start the server by

```
bundle exec thin start
```

And it works cause i now get answer from this command

```
curl http://localhost:3000
```

Comment: Your `curl` request, is it to port `300` or `3000`? `3000` is more common in Rails.

Comment: You need to allow port 3000 in your firewall.

Comment: :) 3000. that was a typo here, not in my prompt

Comment: @Jepzen issue `telnet localhost 3000`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev for localhost it isn't =)

Comment: I tried iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT but still no luck.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ result: telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: What ip address should i set in the thin yml file? I tried changing it from 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Jepzen please `cat /etc/thin/testapp.yml`

Comment: @Jepzen what is in the **log/thin.log**

Comment: I have two folders for thin in /etc. One called thin1.9.1/ and one called thin1.8/ Can find the thin.log

Comment: @Jepzen rename 1.8 to an other name, and try to find the log. and how do you run the *thin*?

Comment: run in console on your server 'ifconfig'. you will see server IP. Try to open in browser <IP>, or <IP>:3000

Comment: Theere is no folder named log in the thin. Renamed the folder now. I was planning to start it up as a service by doing this sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f thin defaults

Comment: @Jepzen at first, attain the `thin` has run successfully from the command line

Comment: use `netstat -ntlp | grep 3000` to see if it is actually running. If the command returns something it will also tell you which IP it's listening on.

Comment: $ bundle exec thin start
>> Using rack adapter
>> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop

Comment: @arco444 it returns nothing

Comment: @Jezpen that would suggest it's not starting properly... try the command without the grep, that will return you a list of every process that's listening on a socket. Maybe you'll see it in the list. Needs to be run with sudo too, I should have added...

Comment: @arco444 Yes i got the sudo. When i do it without grep it does not list anything listen on port 3000. Only apache on 80 and ssh on 22. So i guess we now know the service is not starting correctly..

Comment: just set the the *rvm* enviromnent in `rc.local`, and run *thin* as you did. for example: `#!bin/bash -l  ;
source "/path/to/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
cd /path/to/rails
nuhup bundle exec thin start &
`

Comment: But I wish to make it start up as a serivce. If i do like this i would have to do everytime i boot up right?